Rule of succession with informative prior probability
Suppose I perform $n\geq 0$ conditionally independent Bernoulli trials with unknown probability $1\geq p\geq 0$ and I measure $n \geq s \geq 0$ successes. Additionally, suppose that $1\geq\tilde{p}\geq 0$ is my best estimate for $p$ if $n=0$.
I would like to have an informative prior probability for the rule of succession in order to estimate $p$. My idea was using the Beta distribution $\text{Beta}(\tilde{p},1-\tilde{p})$ which has the mean value $\tilde{p}$. The problem is that my distribution matches Jeffreys' prior probability $\text{Beta}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ for $\tilde{p}=\frac{1}{2}$, which is usually considered an uninformative prior.
Whatever prior probability I choose, I would like to generalize the result for Bernoulli trials with $k\geq 2$ possible outcomes, where $1\geq p_1,\dots,p_k \geq 0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i = 1$ are the respective unknown probabilities and $1\geq \tilde{p}_1,\dots,\tilde{p}_k \geq 0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \tilde{p}_i = 1$ are my respective best estimates if $n=0$.
I believe that there are many different informative prior probabilities which could be used, but I struggle to find a satisfactory solution. I am mostly interested in the formula for the rule of succession. Any guidance would be appreciated.
